# How do i change color of letters of sectionIndexTitlesForTableView? is it possible in iphone?

Tags: iphone, header, uicolor

I have to change the color of sectionIdexTitle for table view??how to do this?
any one knows it ??please tell me??

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  You will have to use a custom view with:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Then you can create your own UILabel with whatever color you want.

Comment: through this we can change the header view color but how to change color of that side sectionIdexTitle

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6 you can do that.

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSectionIndexColor:)]) {
        tableView.sectionIndexColor = ... ;  // some color
}
```